# header and footer of the first page of every chapter

Tags: chapters, header-footer

It maby be weird, I want to make header and footer for every page including the first page of each chapter, how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example, if you use `fancyhdr`, you could write

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

in your preamble. Then, all first pages of chapters, which would have plain style, would show fancy style. Or use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}`, see the `fancyhdr` manual for this.

Or use `\let\ps@plain\ps@headings` instead, or generally use your page style name after `\ps@`. `\ps@plain` stands for plain page style and can be reassigned this way.

Comment: or use the `memoir` class and alias its `chapter` pagestyle to something more suitable.

Comment: ... or use one of the `KOMA-Script` classes and redefine `\chapterpagestyle`.