# fancy header/footer on pages with chapter beginning

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I'd like to produce `report` class document with one style of page numbering.

I've declared:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

but on pages with new chapter the page numbers are centered.

How can I protect my `fancy` setting form overwriting by `chapter` settings or how can I define my own header and footer for those pages?

Thanks for any approach.

Comment: Duplicate of or related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15170/header-and-footer-of-the-first-page-of-every-chapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make known the plain page style to fancyhdr

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
```