# Why doesn't \pagestyle{empty} work on the first page of a chapter?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

Here's a minimal case of the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first}

This page has a page number\ldots

\newpage

\ldots but not this one.

\end{document}
```

I've surmised (by removing it) that the problem has something to do with the `\chapter` line.  But what caused this issue and how do I correct it?

Comment: I had to look at \ldots twice, I thought it said \idiots.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The page style for the first page of a chapter is set internally (in the `book` and `report` document classes) to be `plain`; you can change this behaviour by adding the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{empty}% original style: plain
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

or, using the `etoolbox` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

If the `plain` style is not needed elsewhere, then you can redefine it to be the `empty` page style; this can be done with:

```
\makeatletter
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

Finally, in the `scrbook` document class (from the `KOMA-Script` bundle), the style for the first page of chapters can be changed simply by redefining the `\chapterpagestyle` command, as in:

```
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}
```

EDIT: added egreg's remarks.

Comment: If one doesn't need the `plain` pagestyle elsewhere, the easiest way is to say `\let\ps@plain\ps@empty` (surrounded by the usual pair of commands). Your code can be simplified with **etoolbox** as `\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}`

Comment: @egreg: yes. I will add theses remarks to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It always surprises me how quickly questions are answered (especially when I plan to self-answer).  I appreciate knowing other ways to do things, however.  So thanks.  When I've had this issue in the past, I almost always want to change just one chapter and not every chapter in a document, so `\thispagestyle` is the usual solution.

Answer (score 33):

The `\chapter` command internally uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Add `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This page has a page number\ldots

\newpage

\ldots but not this one.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've had this problem at least twice and probably many more times, so I figured writing (and answering) this question would help me remember.  I'll likely accept this answer when I'm able.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jon: Actually, I like your answer better.

Comment: This is a good solution for setting the page style to empty for specific chapters, rather than all of them.

Answer (score 13):

The reason this happens is that the `\chapter` macro resets the `pagestyle` for that page.  It makes sense when you think about it since you usually want the first page of a chapter to look different than other pages.  For instance, if the page number normally sits on the top of the page, you will want to move it to the bottom of the chapter title page.  It would look strange otherwise.

There are a number of fixes for the problem, but the easiest is to put `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after the `\chapter` macro.

If you'd rather change *every* chapter page, you could use the `memoir` class and redefine the `chapter` pagestyle:

```
\makepagestyle{chapter}
```

See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-head-and-footlines-for-pages-between-chapters) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15170/header-and-footer-of-the-first-page-of-every-chapter).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\assignpagestyle` from `titlesec` package :

```
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it doesnt work with my documentclass{book}?

Answer (score 3):

I find that when styling the caption it ist necessary for \thispagestyle{empty} to be *inside* of it:

Thus:

```
\part*{\color[HTML]{636060}{A: Lipsum Caption}\thispagestyle{empty}}\label{sec:Kap01}
```

will suppress the page number, whereas

```
\part*{\color[HTML]{636060}{A: Lipsum Caption}}\thispagestyle{empty}\label{sec:Kap01}
```

won't.