# \pagestyle{empty} on a specific number of pages

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I would like to remove the style of my report on my table of contents.

I formerly used `\thispagestyle{empty}` before  `\tableofcontents` but it obviously works only for the first page of the table of contents.

Since my table of contents is now 3 pages, is there a way/options to make a `\pagestyle{empty}` for an amount of 3 pages only, and then go back with my early own style for the rest of my repport?

Please note that my created style includes headers/images/page number on top and on bottom of each page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you wrote the command `\thispagestyle` works only for one page. To manipulate the header/footer of more pages you have to work with `\pagestyle`. You can't limit the command `\pagestyle` to a specific number of pages. So you have to switch to you favorit page style after `\tableofcontents`.

You can do:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{headings}
```

If you are working with a class which provides the level `\chapter` you have to do a little bit more as explained here: [Why doesn't \pagestyle{empty} work on the first page of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter)

Comment: I have 3 pages for tableofcontens i want just to remove page style in those pages not all the pages