# Remove header and footer in titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, titletoc

With the standard TOC, I use this code :

```
%make the second and other page from TOC without header and footer
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}% <cmd>
 {\@starttoc}% <search>
 {\thispagestyle{empty}\@starttoc}
 {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

and this code :

```
%make the first page from TOC without header and footer
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

And it's working perfectly. But now, I'm trying to write a document with big Appendix. So I write the document in separated files and use the command `\include` at the end of my master document.

I need to write a separately TOC for my big Appendix, so I'm trying to use the package `titletoc`. Actually, both the TOCs are correctly generated with this code :

```
\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{0}{}
\chapter{blabla}
\chapter{bloblo}
...
\stopcontents
```

And the same code in the included appendix.

My problem is simple: how to remove header and footer in TOC generated by the `titletoc` package? Obviously, I tried this for the first page :

```
\printcontents{ }{0}{}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

And I have no idea how to patch the command `\printcontents` like the command `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: You dont need to patch, call `\pagestyle{empty}` before `\tableofcontents`, and after, `\pagestyle{plain/fancy/whatever}` to change it back. `\thispagestyle{...}` only works for a single page, it automatically reverts to the existing style thereafter.

Comment: Related or duplicated: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/pagestyleempty-on-a-specific-number-of-pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/pagestyleempty-on-a-specific-number-of-pages/116080#116080)

Comment: I have already tried this method, Marco. But i'm not satisfied from the result. If i do :

`\pagestyle{empty}
\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{0}{}{}
\pagestyle{plain}`

The second page from my TOC have the plain footer. If i had a `\clearpage` after the `\printcontents`, the second page from my TOC have the empty footer but now i have an empty page with my plain footer before the first chapter...

Answer (score 3):

The command `\thispagestyle{empty}` works also with `titletoc`. The example below creates two tocs whereby both has no header/footer:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\startcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printcontents{ }{0}{}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\stopcontents

\clearpage
\appendix
\startcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printcontents{ }{0}{}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\stopcontents
\end{document}
```