# Page numbering with filled circles in all pages

Tags: page-numbering

I have a code for printing page numbers in filled circles. But it only appears in even numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=gray!50,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

% header style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\section{Chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not with *all* odd pages; the problem is with pages that internally have assigned the `plain` style (which, with the default settings, happen to be odd), such as the first page of each chapter. You can redefine `plain` to give you the desired formatting:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=gray!50,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

% header style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\section{Chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` is missing in `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`: the rule over the chapter title *must* be removed. The page numbers in a filled circle are not the best typographical device I would think to, to be honest.

Comment: @egreg I'll remove it right away :)

Answer (score 3):

This is very much the same problem as in [Why doesn't `\pagestyle{empty}` work on the first page of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19738/5764) The first page of every chapter is issued with the `plain` page style by default. You'll either have to redefine `plain`, or add some adjustments to the `\chapter` command to not issue `plain`.

The minimal example below patches `\chapter` to insert a different page style - newly-defined using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) - called `chapter`. The `chapter` page style only inserts a footer with circled page numbers, but no headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,tikz,etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=gray!50,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

% header style
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}
\fancypagestyle{chapter}{% New chapter page style/used with chapter first-pages only
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\circled{\thepage}}
}

% Replace chapter first-page page style from 'plain' to 'chapter'
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{chapter}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext

\section{Chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```