# Memoir different footer for Chapter page and the rest

Tags: header-footer, memoir

Is there a way to define a different footer for the page that starts a Chapter and the rest of the document in memoir and customise both easily - possibly something like `\makechapfoot`?

Comment: Possible, I think, but do you have some code to provide or shall we make educated guesses?

Comment: I was able to make both the same using this:`\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{%
  \thispagestyle{chapter}}{%
    \thispagestyle{standard}%
  }{%
}{}` - there must be a better way  to edit the style of Chapter footer?

Comment: As far as I know the `\thispagestyle{...}` statements are hardcoded. You can do the patch (there's nothing bad with that!) or change the definition of the `chapter` pagestyle depending on the first chapter page etc. Patching is easier, I think

Comment: Chapters use the chapter page style, which is just an alias for plain. Make a new page style, give it your own name and alias the chapter style to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily customize the page styles (header or footer) with a `<page style>` in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) using

```
\makeevenhead{<page style>}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
\makeoddhead {<page style>}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
\makeevenfoot{<page style>}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
\makeoddfoot {<page style>}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
```

Note that the above requires `<page style>` to exist. The following exists by default (see section **7.2 Page styles** in the [`memoir` basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)):

[image]

Your specific interest lies with the `chapter` page style - associated with `\chapter`s - and the `headings` page style - the remainder of the document.

Therefore, to change the footer of the `chapter` page style is *easy*:

```
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{Left}{Centre}{Right}
```

<sub>Copying the page style is only needed because `chapter` is actually an "alias" of the `plain` page style. Alternatively, you can modify the `plain` page style directly: `\makeoddfoot{plain}{Left}{Centre}{Right}`</sub>

For the remainder of the document body, you can modify the `headings` page style

```
\makeevenfoot{headings}{Left}{Centre}{Right}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{Left}{Centre}{Right}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds her/himself having the same problem, there is no trivial way of doing this, but some methods have been posted here:

[Why doesn't \pagestyle{empty} work on the first page of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter)

Also see the comments on the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention "there is no trivial way of doing this" when using something as simple as `\makeoddfoot{plain}{..}{..}{..}` does what you want.