# Removing page numbers from pre-textual pages

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

I am writing a text that an be divided in two groups pre-textual elements and the textual elements. The pre-textual elements contains things like table of contents, table of figures, list of abbreviations, etc; and the textual elements are chapters of the text.

What I want to do is remove the page numbering from the pre-textual elements.

First approach i used was using `thispagestyle{empty}` under each pre-textual element. It worked, but when there is, for example, a table of contents or list with two or more pages, just the last page of that element will have its number removed.

Second approach, I tried using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in the beginning of the document, and when I wanted the numbers to appear, I changed to `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. The problem with this approach, is that the numbers will start from 1 in the place I put this last command, and I don't want that. I want the pre-textual pages to be counted, just not appear. I know that I can set the page numbering to start from a certain number, but I would need to do it manually, and always count by myself the number of pages that comes before.

Third approach was using the method I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter). This worked fine, until I noticed that pages where my chapters starts was without numbering. No problem I used the `\thispagestyle{headings}` after each `\chapter` and it was ok. But when I added my references in the end, the first page was without style.

My question is: is there an easiest way to remove the page numbers from a certain group of pages and only there, without facing these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for dummy text

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\emptystyles}{%
\let\oldplain\ps@plain
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\pagestyle{empty}}

\newcommand*{\restorestyles}{%
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\let\ps@plain\oldplain
\pagestyle{headings}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\emptystyles

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\restorestyles

\blinddocument % chapters of dummy text
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you use the `book` class and its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` features, which we can modify. So, if you change your mind, your document is not clobbered with strange commands.

```
\documentclass{book}

% access at the internals of the class, with care
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \pagestyle{empty}%
}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \let\ps@plain\bookps@plain
  \pagestyle{headings}%
}
\let\bookps@plain\ps@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\newcommand{\fakechapter}{% just for filling up
  \chapter{Title}
  \section{A}
  x
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \section{A}
  x
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \section{A}
  x
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \section{A}
  x
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
}

\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter
\fakechapter

\end{document}
```

The `plain` page style is made equivalent to `empty` in the front matter (your “pretextual material”), but a copy of it is kept in a safe place, to be restored when `\mainmatter` is processed.

If you use `fancyhdr` for the headers and footers, similar changes can be made.