# Table of Contents show chapter name in footer and header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

Having a `book` document class, I am trying to achieve having **different** footer/headers for the first page of every chapter.

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741/125011) instructions, I have defined the following custom style, using `titlesec`:

```
\newpagestyle{pageHeaderStyle}{%
  \setfoot
  {}
  {\vcenteredhbox{\confidentialClause}}
  {\thepage}
}
```

And then change the chapter first page style by using:

```
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
      \thispagestyle{pageHeaderStyle}
      \global\@topnum\z@
      \@afterindentfalse
      \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Everything works fine for every chapter except the **ToC**, which outputs `CONTENTS` at both header and footer, like below:

[image]

While the expected behaviour (that works fine in the rest of chapters) is:

[image]

Comment: `\tableofcontents` uses `\chapter*` which is apparently not catched with your `titlesec` approach

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Any hints on how should I approach this, then? Thanks

Comment: Well, not really without seeing your full code. Fragments aren't useful. I also doubt that `titlesec` and a redefinition of `\chapter` will go well together

Comment: The `\secdef` macro `\def\secdef#1#2{\@ifstar{#2}{\@dblarg{#1}}}` causes `\chapter` to execute `\@chapter` and `\chapter*` to execute `\@schapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to adapt `\thispagestyle` in the `\chapter` command 'dynamically' by replacing it with a `\@currentthispagestyle`, which is set with `\SetCurrentPageStyle`

I used `fancyhdr` (because I am more familiar with that package) and `tcolorbox` (since I don't know where `\vcenteredhbox` comes from)

Since `\@currentthispagestyle` defaults to `plain`, the ToC will use the plain style.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{confbox/.style={nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    sharp corners, 
    boxrule=2pt,
    colframe=red,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    colupper=red,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries}
}

\usepackage[headheight=35pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\confidentialClause}{CONFIDENTIAL}


%Define a page style
\fancypagestyle{confidentialheader}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\tcbox[confbox]{\confidentialClause}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@currentthispagestyle}{plain}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetCurrentPageStyle}{om}{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\@currentthispagestyle}{#1}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\@currentthispagestyle}{#2}%
  }%
  \pagestyle{#2}%
}

% Perform a patch to change 'plain' to `\@currentthispagestyle`
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{\@currentthispagestyle}}{}{}
}



\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\SetCurrentPageStyle{confidentialheader}
\chapter{Foo}
\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]