# How to remove the anormal space from the chapter title?

Tags: sectioning, pdftex

How to remove the anormal space from the chapter title, i worked with fancyhdr package.
Here is the whole latex book style:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{thesis}[2015/06/22 Thesis class (E. Scifo), V1.0]

% base class = book 
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt,oneside]{book}



% packages 
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[small, bf, up]{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\it \small}

%\RequirePackage{subfigure}

\RequirePackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%% for tables
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{multicol}

\RequirePackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\RequirePackage[left]{lineno} %% line numbers
\modulolinenumbers[5] %% numbers each 5 lines only

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
%% page geometry
\RequirePackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{}}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{}}

%\geometry{a4paper, body={160mm,245mm}}


%% Toc at begining of chapter
\RequirePackage[]{minitoc}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Chapter content}


%% Hyperref
\RequirePackage{hyperref} % hyperlink for easier navigation in the document
\hypersetup{
  backref=page,% add links into...
  pagebackref=true,%... references
  hyperindex=true, % add links in index
  colorlinks=true, % add colors to links
  breaklinks=true, % break line in long links
  urlcolor= blue, % hyperlink color
  linkcolor= blue, % external link color
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  plainpages=false,% use i, ii, iii... page numbers in pdf readers
  bookmarks=true, %
  pdfa = true,
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Chapitre}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{nameref}  





%% Epigraph style
\RequirePackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphrule}{0.1pt} % bottom line width
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\makeatletter
% Taken and updated from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.dtx
\renewcommand{\@epitext}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\textflush} \hspace*{20pt} \itshape #1 \normalfont \\
      \ifdim\epigraphrule>\z@ \@epirule \else \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip} \fi
\end{\textflush}\end{minipage}}
\makeatother

%% Opening quotes
\RequirePackage{fancybox}
\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(-15,-15){\scalebox{3}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(15,-15){\scalebox{3}{''}}}

\newcommand\chapQuote[2]{
  \vskip-0.5cm
  \begin{flushright}
    \boxput*(0.35,-0.9){
      \colorbox{white}{\textsc{#2}}}{
      %\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
      %\cornersize{4}
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
      \colorbox{white}{\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
          \openquote
          \itshape #1
          \closequote
      \end{minipage}}
    }
  \end{flushright}
  \vskip1cm
}


%% Dedication
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\newenvironment{dedication}
               {\cleardoublepage           % we want a new page
                 \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
                 \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
                 \itshape             % the text is in italics
                 \hspace{3cm}
                 \noindent%
                 \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                   \noindent%
               }
               { \end{minipage}
                 \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
                 \cleardoublepage           % finish off the page
               }



%% customize chapter headings
%% Source : http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/modification-du-style-de-chapitre-t7022.html
\makeatletter
\newlength{\chapter@number@width}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\normalfont
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \vspace*{10pt}%
    \settowidth{\chapter@number@width}{%
      \hbox{\color{white}\Huge\bfseries
        \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
        \thechapter
        \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
    }}
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \hsize=\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+\tabcolsep+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}
          \scshape\strut\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}\@chapapp\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}} \\
          \fboxsep=0pt
          \colorbox{black}{\vbox{%
              \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+4pt{}}
              \hbox{\color{white}\Huge\bfseries
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                \thechapter
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
              }
              \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 0pt
              \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
              \hbox{\parbox{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\vphantom{E}}}
          }}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \vtop{%
        \advance\hsize by -\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
        \hspace*{-0.5cm}\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \scshape\strut\vphantom{\@chapapp} \\
          \fboxsep=0pt
          \colorbox{white}{\vbox{%
              \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
              \hbox{\LARGE\bfseries
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                \phantom{\thechapter}
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
              }
              \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
              \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
              \hbox{\hspace*{3pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\scshape #1}}
          }}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
    \vspace{50pt}%
  }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\normalfont
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \vspace*{10pt}%
    \settowidth{\chapter@number@width}{%
      \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
        \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
        \thechapter
        \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
    }}
    \hbox{%
      \vtop{%
        \hsize=\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+\tabcolsep+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}
          \scshape\strut\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}\phantom{\@chapapp}\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}} \\
          \fboxsep=0pt
          \colorbox{black}{\vbox{%
              \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
              \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                \phantom{\thechapter}%
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
              }
              \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 0pt
              \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
              \hbox{\parbox{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\vphantom{E}}}
          }}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \vtop{%
        \advance\hsize by -\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
        \hspace*{-0.5cm}\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \scshape\strut\vphantom{\@chapapp} \\
          \fboxsep=0pt
          \colorbox{white}{\vbox{%
              \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
              \hbox{\LARGE\bfseries
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                \phantom{\thechapter}
                \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
              }
              \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
              \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
              \hbox{\hspace*{20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-30pt}{\Huge\bfseries\scshape #1}}
          }}%
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
    \vspace{50pt}%
  }
}
%% remove the top line : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}% original style: plain
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother



%% customize title page
\RequirePackage{pgffor} 
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\unilogo#1{\def\@unilogo{#1}}
\def\lablogo#1{\def\@lablogo{#1}}
\def\university#1{\def\@university{#1}}
\def\docschool#1{\def\@docschool{#1}}
\def\lab#1{\def\@lab{#1}}
\def\field#1{\def\@field{#1}}
\def\defensedate#1{\def\@defensedate{#1}}
\def\serienumber#1{\def\@serienumber{#1}}

\def\njurymembers#1{\def\@njurymembers{#1}}

\newcommand{\addjurymember}[4]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @juryTitle#1\endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @juryName#1\endcsname{#3}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @juryFunction#1\endcsname{#4}
}

\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}

\def\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1.5cm}
  \hspace{-0.4cm}

  \begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}p{6cm}p{6cm}}
    \ifdef{\@unilogo}{
      \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{\@unilogo}}{} &
    \ifdef{\@lablogo}{
    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{\@lablogo}}{} & 
    \ifdef{\@serienumber}{
    \raisebox{3em}{\@serienumber}}{}
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{center} 
    \vskip1.5cm 

    \ifdef{\@university}{
      \textsc{\Huge \@university}}{~}\\[1cm]
    \ifdef{\@docschool}{
      \textsc{\LARGE \@docschool}}{~}\\[0.2cm]
    \ifdef{\@lab}{
      \textsc{\LARGE \@lab}}{~} \\[0.5cm]

    \ifdef{\@field}{
      \textsc{\LARGE Discipline : \@field}}{~}\\[1.5cm]

    \textsc{\Huge Thèse de doctorat}\\[0.5cm]

    {\Large Soutenue le
    \ifdef{\@defensedate}{
      \@defensedate}{\today}~par}\\[1.cm]

    \ifdef{\@author}{
      \textsc{\Huge \@author}}{~} \\[1cm]

    \vskip1.cm
    \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
      \Huge \bfseries \centering
      \@title
    \end{minipage}

    \vskip2.cm

    \resettabtoks
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\@njurymembers} {%
      \-\hspace{0.7cm}
      \eaddtabtoks{ {\csname @juryTitle\n\endcsname} }
      \eaddtabtoks{ {\csname @juryName\n \endcsname} }
      \addtabtoks{ & }
      \eaddtabtoks{({\csname @juryFunction\n \endcsname }) }
      \addtabtoks{ \\ }
    }%

    %% http://tlsflyleaf.onada.fr/down.php
    \ifnum \@njurymembers=0
    Jury members
    \else
    \begin{table}[h!] \large
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{0.34\textwidth}}}          
          \printtabtoks
        \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
    \end{table}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}

\makeatother
```

[image: chapter title]

Comment: add `\raggedright` at the point that you specify your chapter heading fonts

Comment: can you be more precise.

Comment: no as you have given no clues.  the layout you show is non standard so somewhere you have specified some layout for a chapter heading, currently that layout is specifying a justified paragraph so tex is stretching the spaces to fit the width, you need to modify that code that you have not shown to make a ragged right paragraph instead.

Comment: i gave the whole code source, where should i modify?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1):

Your chapter heading is set in a `\parbox` by this line

```
\hbox{\hspace*{3pt}\parbox{%
        \dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-20pt}%
              {\Huge\bfseries\scshape #1}}
```

so add `\raggedright` along with the font to get

```
\hbox{\hspace*{3pt}\parbox{%
        \dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-20pt}%
              {\Huge\bfseries\scshape\raggedright #1}}
```

Comment: thank you, you saved me, what if i want the title in lower case letters.

Comment: @zyadelkhadir delete `\scshape` in the same line

Comment: How to do the same for page headers (lowercase letters)

Comment: I don't see anything there that changes the page head, but anyway that's a different question (there will be a `\scshape` or `\textsc{..]` in some code you are using that needs deleting.  But why start with such a complicated class if you want to change the layout, much easier to start with something simple like article or book class and add things that you want than try to remove things from a non standard class.