# Problems with \chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm writing my thesis and I want to get chapters. However between the end of one chapter and the next there is a blank page, except for the page number and title of the chapter that is ending. How do I solve this?

Also after I added the chapters my pages started alternating between having an indentation and not having one. How do I get rid of the indentation?

Comment: As always one this site please provide a full but minimal example showing what you are doing and that others can copy and test as is. As your question stands, we have no idea what you are doing, what class your are using, preamble or how you organize your document, so please help us help you.

Comment: Have you by any chance been using `\chapter{title} \include{chapter_title}....` as we've seen that one before.

Comment: As @daleif said this depends on your documentclass. For default classes and classes based on those https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111580/removing-an-unwanted-page-between-two-chapters might help. If you use the `fancyhdr` package then maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477253/how-to-remove-blank-page-before-my-new-report-chapter is relevant. But it would be best if you post a minimal document to determine what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

For the empty page with page number and page headings, I assume you use `openright` option for yout class (like \documentclass[openright]{book}).  Then you could use the package `emptypage`, and all such pages will be really blanck. If you use option `openany`, this empty page will be gone.

For the indentation/no-indentation, you have two options.

1. If you want all paragraphs *with* indentation, even the 1st one, use package `indentfirtst`
2. If you ant all paragraphs *without* indentation, use package `parskip`, that removes indentation and adds a skip after each paragraph.

Comment: Without having seen what the OP is actually doing, this seems a shot in the dark.