# How can I make the page on which a book part begins have no page number

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering, parts

I'm writing a book in two parts, but for some (silly if you ask me) reason whoever designed the `book` document class in TeX decided part pages needed numbers. How can I remove them?

I tried the following code, which I found [here](https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/OmcHowJy/book-part-title-pages-without-page-numbering):

```
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
\***@openright
\cleardoublepage
\else
\clearpage
\fi
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\***@twocolumn
\onecolumn
\@tempswatrue
\else
\@tempswafalse
\fi
\null\vfil
\secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{9.5cm}
```

(I have no idea what the `epigraph` and `lettrine` packages do or  whether they're needed.) However, this returns the following error when attempting to compile (XeLaTeX, for compatibility with other preamble code I have):

> `Extra \else.`

(It did seem odd to me when I looked at that bit of code that there are `\else`s and `\fi`s but no `\if`s.)

I've also (perhaps naïvely) tried adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately before or after the `\part{}` command in my document, but that didn't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside=off,chapterprefix=on,appendixprefix=on]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}
\part{Teil eins}
\chapter{Kapitel eins}
\end{document}
```

If possible, I would like to keep the `book` class. I've read that `scrbook` and `memoir` make it easier to achieve what I want, but I have code in my preamble which is incompatible with those classes and I really don't want to start debugging that.

Comment: The code you found is a really bad attempt at redefining `\part` in `book.cls`, and it leaves out some very important `\if` components.  It is not at all a good model (aside from its being 15 years old).  The page style in the current `book.cls` is `\pagestyle{plain}`, which can simply be patched (based on what's done in the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741): `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}`

Comment: Here's the link again. I hope it solves the problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter

Comment: I think that this has nothing to do with the `epigraph` package (don't know about `letrine`); try not using them or anything based on them and see if things improve.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yep, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to banish the page number from a `\part` page when using the `book` class is to patch the definition of `\part` using the patch command defined in `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

(More details regarding similar patching of the first page of a chapter can be found in the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741 from which I adapted this answer.)