# Why won't the titlesec package modify \chapter headings? (PDFLaTeX)

Tags: chapters, titlesec, article

It seems to me that `titlesec` is failing to set `\chapter` heading styles in documents.

The documentation says that it should have support to set `\chapter` heading styles.

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\centering\bfseries\huge}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[0.8pt]}[]
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt}
{0pt}
{0pt}[0pt]

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\centering\Large}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1.6pt]}[]
\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt}
{0pt}
{0pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
\chapter{CHAPTER TEXT}\label{chapter-text}
\section{SECTION TEXT}\label{section-text}
\end{document}
```

This fails both in my local installation of PDFLatex and in Overleaf.
[image: screenshot of the error in overleaf]

Perhaps I am missing something. Does anyone have a clue as to what might resolve this issue for me? Thank you!

Comment: the article class has no chapters. Did you try with report or book?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using `\documentclass{report}` or `\documentclass{book}` does fix the issue! I did not know that the `article` class has no support for chapters. Thank you! Would you mind writing an answer so that I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `article` document class does not define `\chapter` headings, and therefore it is not possible to give them styles.

The solution (Suggested in a comment by [@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)) is to switch to another document class, such as `report` or `book`. This works!

I chose to switch to the `report` document class. Note that this caused a migration issue: my headers (set by `\pagestyle`) refused to work on the same page as the `\chapter` heading. I found the solution to this issue in another forum post here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741/315958

Answer (score 0):

You could instead wrap your definition for `\chapter` inside an `\@ifundefined` (note to enclose this with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`).

```latex
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\centering\bfseries\huge}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\titlerule[0.8pt]}[]
    \titlespacing{\chapter}
    {0pt}
    {0pt}
    {0pt}[0pt]
}
\makeatother
```

This way, you can keep the `\chapter` style independently of the documentclass.

---

**Clarification:** This solution was never meant to provide the `\chapter` command for `article` class, but to keep the `\chapter` style *re*definitions regardless of the document class used.
As @UlrikeFischer mentioned, `article` does not provide `\chapter`, and this is for a reason, which also justifies the existence of `book` and `report`.
I personally find it very wrong to provide chapters in articles.

However, as OP asked, one can use `titlesec` and `titletoc` to define a `\chapter` command. This could be done as follows (I tried to be close to the original, might not be perfect):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@chapapp}{\chaptername}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\chapter}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{chapter}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}
    {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter}
    {20pt}
    {\Huge\bfseries}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
    {0pt}
    {50pt}
    {40pt}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em]
    {\vspace*{10pt}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{1.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \gdef{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\end{document}
```

Note however that this is wrong on many levels.
For example, the `book` and `report` classes use `\chapter*` to automatically issue the headings of `\tableofcontents`, `\begin{thebibliography}{...}`, `\printindex`, etc., while the `article` class uses `\section*` for this.
Moreover, I have not accounted for markings which are used in the header of each page (similar to other information like page number).
The `book` and `report` classes define `\chaptermark` for this, but obviously `article` does not have that.

Comment: This is not a solution for the question asked. The code here does not implement the `\chapter` heading styles in a document class where `\chapter` is missing. This code checks if the `\chapter` command exists before declaring styles for it, but does not implement `\chapter` otherwise. So the problem persists - there is still no `\chapter` heading in the `article` document class so `\chapter` is unable to be styled. Please update your answer to include a way to "keep the `\chapter` style independently of the documentclass." or change the claims of your post to make it correct.

Comment: This is useful when creating a preamble that could be used for any document class, but again, it does not solve the problem that was given. Maybe update the answer to say that.