# Pagenumbering on every "first chapter" page

Tags: page-numbering

Using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}


\makeatletter
\let\latexps@plain\ps@plain   % Store definition
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty        % Use empty pagestyle (ps)
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables


\clearpage
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\latexps@plain   % restore pagestyle 'plain' 
\makeatother


\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

I would like to restore pagestyle 'headings'. I have tried

```
\clearpage
\makeatletter
\let\ps@headings\latexps@headings   
\makeatother
```

that does not work (still 'empty'), then using just

`\pagestyle{headings}`

works, but it does not work on every "first chapter page" that is still without headings , numbering ("empty"). Other pages are ok. How to get "headings" to these pages?

Comment: So you want "first chapter page[s]" to also adhere to `\pagestyle{headings}`?

Comment: See [header and footer of the first page of every chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15170/5764). You may be requiring `\let\ps@plain\ps@headings`. There are a number of other posts similar to this on the site. They're just mixed in with bizarre titles, and not always easy to find.